# Need help in designing a communication to on-premise software from SaaS

Tags: architecture, cloud, software-design

I am planning a solution for creating a communication from SaaS to on-prem software. 
Some details:

1. Java WEB servers with REST API
2. ~10K servers
3. No global access

**My goal is invoke REST API calls on those servers.**

My approach is to create a light weight "agent" software that sits behind the firewall and initiates the communication with the cloud 'relay service' (thereby avoiding firewall issues). It can maintain a bi-directional connection whether with pull or push based approaches using (or abusing) the HTTP protocol.
Other services will communicate to on-premise servers through the relay service.

My design considerations:

1. Should I use web sockets or HTTP long poll technique?
2. Whether the SaaS service response arrive synchronously or asynchronously? In other words, will requestor services blocked until a response arrive or the response will be pushed when available. A relay service will manage requests lifecycle for progress monitoring.
3. Scaling out the cloud service
4. Request & response size should be limited due to indirect communication?
5. Is another approach that I am missing?

I would like to learn from your experience with such software systems.

Answer (score 1):

Your plan of having an agent on the remote machine is virtually a requirement to bypass firewalls and other such issues you will run into.  There are details not specified here that are pertinent, so I’m going to make some assumptions.

I’m going to assume that you want the remote server to receive all messages.  In other words, if the remote server goes down and comes back, the messages sent while it was down should still be available.  I’m also going to assume there is no requirement for a real-time “conversation” between the local server and the remote server – that the remote server will receive the message and act on it when convenient for that server.

With those assumptions, you would be better off with a queue messaging system like RabbitMQ, Amazon SQS, or Azure Queue Service.  You could create a queue for each remote server (with a predictable name so the remote agent can find it) and the local server could add messages to the queue as necessary.  The agent on the remote server would read from the queue and act upon it (maybe that action is just calling another API and passing along any data).  With a queue you guarantee the remote server will receive all messages intended for it, even if that server is down at the time the message is sent.  This also removes the tight coupling between the remote server and a specific in-house server, thus dramatically improving your scalability and that of the remote client (in case they want to have 2 servers with agents running)

BTW, if you do have a requirement for the two servers to exchange information in real time, you could post a message to the queue for a remote server to “call me”, in which case the remote server opens a web socket to the in-house server just for the communication that needs the more timely interaction.  Other interaction that is not as time sensitive could use the request queue as described above, and a similar response queue for the remote server to post responses for the in-house server to pull from the queue.  With a conversationID in each message, this would also allow for massive scaling on the in-house side.

Another note, depending on your use case durable messaging may be an advantage.  Also take a look at Kafka, AWS Kinesis, or Azure Event Hubs.